# how can i change the hash prefix/format of React-router

Tags: react-router

i'm using react-router in my app. it changes url like this:

`xxx/index.html#/a1`
`xxx/index.html#/a2`

**but i want this:**

`xxx/index.html#!/a1`
`xxx/index.html#!/a2`

because of my old app config.
i dont want to change the interface.

i had try to like this

    `<Route path="!/">
      <Route name="a1" path="a1" handler={a1}/>
      <Route name="a2" path="a2" handler={a2}/>
    </Route>`

or this

    `<Route path="!">
      <Route name="a1" path="a1" handler={a1}/>
      <Route name="a2" path="a2" handler={a2}/>
    </Route>`

but they all got

`xxx/index.html#/!/a1`

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own [CustomLocation](https://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Custom%20Location).
I've never done this myself, but you could look at the [HashLocation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/285a61f706db83c65269931880238962f470ccd7/modules/HashHistory.js) implementation and change what's necessary.

Then you could just pass it to `Router.run`

```
Router.run(routes, MyCustomLocation, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

Comment: when i visit https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/locations/HashLocation.js  . i get a 404

Comment: It looks like react-router changed the location of the file. Changed it to a permanent link.